# bind lists together giving me incorrect results when using bind_rows, do.call(rbind,.) and plyr::ldply

Tags: r

I cannot seem to bind my lists together correctly.

I have tried:

```
purrr::map(myList, ~dplyr::bind_rows(.))
Error: Argument 1 must have names
```

Which does not work.

```
purrr::map(myList, ~plyr::ldply(.))
```

Which "appears" to work but does not give me the correct values. When I run:

```
library(dplyr)
purrr::map(myList, ~plyr::ldply(.) %>% 
  distinct(protocol_active))
```

I get the following output:

```
[[1]]
   protocol_active
1        0.4766905
2        0.4277574
3        0.3365723
4        0.4572180
5        0.2857566
6        0.3282195
7        0.3178228
8        0.5150016
9        0.5812856
10       0.4742427

[[2]]
  protocol_active
1               0
```

However in list `[[2]][[6]]` I get the following:

```
myList[[2]][[6]]
      protocol_active                  wind               holiday                  temp 
          0.609327860           0.456351664           0.148564432           0.14033729
```

Where `protocol_active` has a value > 0, but when I run `distinct()` it tells me that list `[[2]]` only hae `0` as its unique value.

What am I doing wrong here?

Data:

```
myList <- list(list(c(protocol_active = 0.476690486794737, wind = 0.421644905580702, 
holiday = 0.237855180468597, month_10 = 0.174138672609035, month_8 = 0.146189977753241, 
temp = 0.136091939119292, month_11 = 0.117059004222591, humidity = 0.0981068528147208, 
weekday = 0.0936421424983979, month_1 = 0.075759335979394, text_scattered_clouds = 0.0714021764373941, 
month_4 = 0.0458588632888939, month_3 = 0.044565083971885, month_12 = 0.0400631134202661, 
month_7 = 0.0396780361927733, month_9 = 0.0313980546969172, month_6 = 0.0307021354848187, 
barometer = 0.0297905815436382, month_5 = 0.0275607431560466, 
text_light_rain = 0.0165770194829191, month_2 = 0.0165630157979537, 
text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0121088618908841, text_sunny = 0.00941388986252044, 
text_fog = 0.00924611477602324, workday_on_holiday = 0.00284118722006891, 
text_passing_clouds = 0.00150433375272096, text_rain = 0.00131183594715628, 
weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0), c(protocol_active = 0.427757390802854, 
wind = 0.408503171009464, month_11 = 0.275057127435594, month_8 = 0.142977205336468, 
temp = 0.138475854744559, weekday = 0.131070281010648, humidity = 0.0898046759674304, 
holiday = 0.086630490993674, month_1 = 0.0596217489313094, month_10 = 0.0551334046364746, 
text_scattered_clouds = 0.0490242183124676, month_12 = 0.045106370859385, 
month_4 = 0.0419702477855225, month_3 = 0.0404903265753906, month_5 = 0.0359349426154136, 
barometer = 0.035618224264753, month_6 = 0.0338249178101483, 
month_7 = 0.0327099416366689, month_9 = 0.0293428124958271, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0270874829871817, 
month_2 = 0.0180123197586705, text_passing_clouds = 0.0118664281453393, 
text_sunny = 0.0103031663280448, text_light_rain = 0.00942806139275789, 
text_fog = 0.00806600748408229, workday_on_holiday = 0.00241487503942681, 
text_rain = 0.0000570347965499609, weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0
), c(wind = 0.336572349791158, holiday = 0.198779253833438, month_1 = 0.192421516318504, 
month_10 = 0.144445315616197, temp = 0.143690255193945, month_11 = 0.137325167540274, 
text_scattered_clouds = 0.10122916446616, humidity = 0.0828318548018303, 
weekday = 0.0823615530607839, month_12 = 0.0737718595642614, 
month_5 = 0.0594576071260418, month_8 = 0.0588273438617596, month_4 = 0.0573095170966537, 
text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0480329543671073, month_6 = 0.0402532857184651, 
barometer = 0.0396320005493679, month_3 = 0.026472471467845, 
month_7 = 0.0262888669729505, month_9 = 0.0259344946067317, text_sunny = 0.0131106700559495, 
month_2 = 0.012995547924582, workday_on_holiday = 0.00982112260492833, 
text_passing_clouds = 0.00683627593864011, protocol_active = 0.00647374322450801, 
text_light_rain = 0.0063248456805146, text_fog = 0.00585607353395349, 
text_rain = 0.000405401311389258, weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0
), c(protocol_active = 0.457218040022404, wind = 0.386653192913039, 
month_11 = 0.271520132187022, holiday = 0.166075296710207, temp = 0.148792881213105, 
weekday = 0.106041161955832, humidity = 0.0929848531838744, month_1 = 0.0928483740915651, 
month_8 = 0.0829540333434191, month_10 = 0.0699121444845427, 
text_fog = 0.0525342428581534, text_scattered_clouds = 0.0522970455826638, 
barometer = 0.0431168167702891, month_7 = 0.0419820798871418, 
month_4 = 0.041477494010643, month_9 = 0.0375248375546493, month_5 = 0.0354565058054496, 
text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0297605077110945, text_passing_clouds = 0.027437090518306, 
month_2 = 0.0271775084449888, month_6 = 0.0217419101984227, text_light_rain = 0.0200993262652359, 
workday_on_holiday = 0.019565240559317, month_3 = 0.0187113693519814, 
month_12 = 0.018413791610736, text_sunny = 0.0099830383163256, 
text_rain = 0.00329234272052351, weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0
), c(wind = 0.285756555215212, month_1 = 0.179849187294914, month_11 = 0.164289483281711, 
holiday = 0.154516151695423, month_10 = 0.150120774452196, temp = 0.134707708686716, 
weekday = 0.0989596352406424, month_12 = 0.0891791624140386, 
text_scattered_clouds = 0.0775458226511579, humidity = 0.0644600094005282, 
month_4 = 0.054180913826995, protocol_active = 0.0535038970887117, 
month_5 = 0.0524276994044104, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0474800352970501, 
month_6 = 0.0472995256777581, month_8 = 0.047177053618853, barometer = 0.035944823214537, 
month_7 = 0.0337175876492492, month_9 = 0.0313097306311111, workday_on_holiday = 0.0255306703510554, 
month_3 = 0.0207022198390048, month_2 = 0.0162812998382264, text_sunny = 0.0105475327224613, 
text_passing_clouds = 0.00751715134937259, text_light_rain = 0.00611453089628769, 
text_fog = 0.00589259659924484, text_rain = 0.00199902163654753, 
weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0), c(wind = 0.328219459502805, 
month_1 = 0.175075058064096, holiday = 0.160793264354813, month_11 = 0.129548105560073, 
text_scattered_clouds = 0.123147537680045, temp = 0.121607173813749, 
month_10 = 0.113682198084755, month_12 = 0.0997093907485133, 
weekday = 0.0832095032532329, month_5 = 0.0608440197523202, humidity = 0.060535465962531, 
month_4 = 0.0584286914194283, month_9 = 0.0447241908785585, barometer = 0.0440128902307778, 
month_8 = 0.0438292939943096, protocol_active = 0.0419578197714128, 
month_3 = 0.0339254215996517, month_6 = 0.0337754882748779, month_7 = 0.031814906735976, 
month_2 = 0.0270908407671335, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0219086588144549, 
text_sunny = 0.0136285604898165, workday_on_holiday = 0.00761672222267062, 
text_light_rain = 0.00634132165607431, text_fog = 0.00608799696248636, 
text_passing_clouds = 0.0040204867146501, text_rain = 0.000376092383049835, 
weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0), c(wind = 0.317822839842299, 
month_11 = 0.19192646205017, holiday = 0.185426564412574, temp = 0.13593219239286, 
month_10 = 0.13277574966079, text_scattered_clouds = 0.0995925773904748, 
month_1 = 0.0979915406435864, weekday = 0.0751849300079218, humidity = 0.0683413140459836, 
month_2 = 0.0640093204816251, month_5 = 0.0611092551132147, month_7 = 0.058891413580269, 
month_6 = 0.0547705294287946, barometer = 0.0514254934314588, 
month_8 = 0.0488036307320211, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0412003813198763, 
month_12 = 0.0411461956492842, month_9 = 0.0286932268469131, 
month_4 = 0.0229876443679717, month_3 = 0.0189662051480523, workday_on_holiday = 0.0112685893702674, 
text_light_rain = 0.0109155125639584, text_passing_clouds = 0.00886646494182724, 
text_fog = 0.00528032941976031, text_rain = 0.00421637095753226, 
text_sunny = 0.00182733590607928, weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0, 
protocol_active = 0), c(protocol_active = 0.51500155823688, wind = 0.369391322961783, 
month_11 = 0.234622367311558, holiday = 0.184593894040067, temp = 0.149243922588351, 
weekday = 0.13568649568242, month_8 = 0.111535093753458, humidity = 0.0831650037468867, 
month_4 = 0.06233952671686, month_5 = 0.0582210814027481, month_1 = 0.0524249054181079, 
month_10 = 0.0513109900081503, text_scattered_clouds = 0.0449822947458677, 
month_6 = 0.0371093226111915, month_7 = 0.0345599941131351, barometer = 0.0306446007250308, 
month_9 = 0.0274106106748507, text_fog = 0.0221568992510268, 
text_passing_clouds = 0.0211599513636558, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0148391773192782, 
month_3 = 0.0141197551543251, month_2 = 0.0140401629120377, workday_on_holiday = 0.00737117942694796, 
text_sunny = 0.00720100269873624, month_12 = 0.00527240881870701, 
text_light_rain = 0.00130866158585655, text_rain = 0.000624886909196766, 
weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0), c(protocol_active = 0.5812855848983, 
wind = 0.388742283293946, month_11 = 0.244592963846307, holiday = 0.158002529973717, 
weekday = 0.122634703648961, temp = 0.119940003635667, month_1 = 0.0838425453701248, 
month_8 = 0.0770040860945533, humidity = 0.0738192673487, month_10 = 0.0610040306320975, 
text_scattered_clouds = 0.0591100941672092, barometer = 0.056244713686979, 
month_5 = 0.0369698544273875, month_9 = 0.036858099182753, month_2 = 0.0310369344611044, 
month_6 = 0.0301084762225969, month_4 = 0.0287642538258338, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0273765916021787, 
month_3 = 0.025851829004895, month_7 = 0.0254969442110151, text_light_rain = 0.0250549811478619, 
text_fog = 0.0222954459465601, workday_on_holiday = 0.0213043972641468, 
text_passing_clouds = 0.0177354853346569, month_12 = 0.00949038839605307, 
text_sunny = 0.00446652838284589, weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0, 
text_rain = 0), c(protocol_active = 0.474242671289945, wind = 0.422109119973802, 
month_10 = 0.18775162510744, holiday = 0.182591428049759, temp = 0.136095003370541, 
month_11 = 0.104629510112073, month_12 = 0.10377588975137, weekday = 0.10162171488075, 
month_8 = 0.0872754275444851, month_1 = 0.0742447916325022, humidity = 0.0667930411502195, 
month_4 = 0.0641386250875992, text_scattered_clouds = 0.058944967751334, 
month_5 = 0.0410161574298865, month_3 = 0.0388656146056763, barometer = 0.0385532707949005, 
month_9 = 0.0370659909291367, month_7 = 0.0351931395507779, month_6 = 0.027635447313099, 
text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0202467735960961, month_2 = 0.0152577431908634, 
text_light_rain = 0.00846413168710652, text_sunny = 0.00513080847316623, 
text_fog = 0.00319036182896425, workday_on_holiday = 0.00303045921527343, 
text_passing_clouds = 0.00235587942164676, text_rain = 0.000150063164697571, 
weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0)), list(c(wind = 0.3471960493154, 
temp = 0.204772614566322, month_8 = 0.119633369487987, humidity = 0.114447660606209, 
holiday = 0.112215067123671, month_10 = 0.109680992791846, month_11 = 0.0949710751650855, 
month_1 = 0.0678540389508553, month_4 = 0.0676970303790074, barometer = 0.0638877490405209, 
weekday = 0.0603264305881994, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.059886928575409, 
month_7 = 0.0523244261699112, month_3 = 0.0464621031121763, text_scattered_clouds = 0.0426460498828706, 
month_5 = 0.0393232886119189, month_9 = 0.0329339301863209, workday_on_holiday = 0.026400691935472, 
month_12 = 0.0239766088909189, month_6 = 0.0209643615779743, 
text_rain = 0.00470063751244484, month_2 = 0.00435824692036667, 
text_fog = 0.00358736017917106, text_passing_clouds = 0.00254604459529451, 
text_light_rain = 0.00246286783930867, text_sunny = 0.000557708446459696, 
weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0, protocol_active = 0), c(protocol_active = 0.546549613644543, 
wind = 0.443618430590955, holiday = 0.2057616408105, temp = 0.143528428632999, 
month_10 = 0.139108116096353, weekday = 0.119753870444551, month_11 = 0.105665854854535, 
month_4 = 0.0847140095491025, humidity = 0.0702211903523539, 
month_5 = 0.067856426839823, month_9 = 0.0585853496855593, barometer = 0.0466051602491349, 
month_8 = 0.0407423583947575, month_1 = 0.0370854357117149, month_6 = 0.0345889221737587, 
month_12 = 0.0331118828706341, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0265744483947316, 
month_3 = 0.0250310123421796, text_light_rain = 0.0236595287710666, 
month_7 = 0.0236081493886604, text_scattered_clouds = 0.0229368038071515, 
month_2 = 0.0119531214563892, text_fog = 0.00546791553037501, 
workday_on_holiday = 0.00441453391159821, text_rain = 0.00314937465607303, 
text_sunny = 0.00282535660389051, text_passing_clouds = 0.00253598129527737, 
weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0), c(protocol_active = 0.518170012744594, 
wind = 0.468760529065347, temp = 0.198249993483989, month_8 = 0.127854839789779, 
holiday = 0.115651709099816, humidity = 0.10895871515734, month_1 = 0.104507054764879, 
weekday = 0.0970008689541525, barometer = 0.0558000887901608, 
month_12 = 0.0520648544022737, month_11 = 0.0498573669270702, 
month_3 = 0.0475327540435148, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0420257895091999, 
month_10 = 0.0392210214613824, month_7 = 0.0346112258522878, 
month_4 = 0.030376681720957, month_6 = 0.0274944621384594, month_9 = 0.0250618364774626, 
workday_on_holiday = 0.0238621021362317, month_5 = 0.0199367708332576, 
text_scattered_clouds = 0.0123115063994457, month_2 = 0.00480323263037882, 
text_sunny = 0.00464160762224322, text_fog = 0.00246012251002589, 
text_light_rain = 0.00221074363608796, text_rain = 0.00193594425875674, 
text_passing_clouds = 0.00193056194592034, weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0
), c(wind = 0.362992887362438, temp = 0.156517904643566, month_12 = 0.114009635327341, 
month_10 = 0.105016643601602, month_7 = 0.101879905068133, barometer = 0.0890323752272844, 
weekday = 0.0883166062815719, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0849764846835166, 
humidity = 0.07626973618123, month_3 = 0.0604644771419713, workday_on_holiday = 0.0598483406595745, 
month_4 = 0.0540825822794581, month_8 = 0.0479107586305469, month_9 = 0.0455382942339936, 
month_1 = 0.036916349709489, holiday = 0.0362250549890437, month_11 = 0.0354289955801871, 
text_scattered_clouds = 0.027544355493611, text_fog = 0.018845295941842, 
text_light_rain = 0.0174401463508169, month_5 = 0.0135907923844196, 
text_rain = 0.0128968099968882, month_6 = 0.012569892360263, 
month_2 = 0.00509965945535965, text_passing_clouds = 0.00139377025885244, 
text_sunny = 0.000367025698946253, weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0, 
protocol_active = 0), c(protocol_active = 0.619563503393299, 
wind = 0.457064448140408, holiday = 0.181107866730898, temp = 0.140728671764677, 
month_11 = 0.129063893852067, weekday = 0.11427594683384, month_10 = 0.0885211368669627, 
month_9 = 0.0783348566882278, month_4 = 0.075404001857456, month_1 = 0.0732684205679306, 
month_3 = 0.0566192154215487, humidity = 0.0469606031303847, 
month_12 = 0.0465199248622981, month_5 = 0.0434354892472862, 
month_8 = 0.0341517087922657, barometer = 0.0340740037986594, 
workday_on_holiday = 0.0271233329090149, text_scattered_clouds = 0.0252819455135321, 
text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0209707050348469, month_7 = 0.020118997730825, 
text_fog = 0.0177517202234142, text_light_rain = 0.0141883356057609, 
month_6 = 0.012501962568832, month_2 = 0.00782442912383458, text_rain = 0.00240311886770778, 
text_sunny = 0.00235140240465584, text_passing_clouds = 0.001641017195825, 
weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0), c(protocol_active = 0.609327859788725, 
wind = 0.456351663566834, holiday = 0.148564431615616, temp = 0.140337292819591, 
month_10 = 0.132416416010628, month_11 = 0.117216315071979, weekday = 0.102646726133412, 
month_9 = 0.0818879473805598, month_1 = 0.0711949855201882, month_4 = 0.0700700130827537, 
humidity = 0.0678324389551247, month_5 = 0.049777553432098, barometer = 0.0466848493424757, 
month_12 = 0.0408083424048677, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0374117362364004, 
month_3 = 0.0289161419390688, month_7 = 0.0254772765149833, text_scattered_clouds = 0.0248008842188115, 
month_8 = 0.0228434387129598, text_rain = 0.0152162249995285, 
text_light_rain = 0.0144390966240625, workday_on_holiday = 0.0139014270811525, 
text_fog = 0.0111675927635563, month_6 = 0.00771660135004278, 
text_passing_clouds = 0.00333411018372105, month_2 = 0.00315501674433698, 
text_sunny = 0.00271693577132569, weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0
), c(wind = 0.341318757984593, temp = 0.181543743016176, month_10 = 0.13695143016574, 
month_1 = 0.11867567475664, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.100970260189399, 
holiday = 0.0980616427161045, barometer = 0.0793575984151815, 
month_7 = 0.0790023186407231, month_11 = 0.0703358960510832, 
weekday = 0.0660567048872761, month_8 = 0.0646335429141987, humidity = 0.0584869976667937, 
month_9 = 0.0550697732815506, month_4 = 0.0549736535127431, text_rain = 0.0324340487643226, 
text_scattered_clouds = 0.029467215459551, month_5 = 0.026095418599204, 
month_12 = 0.0228145297956929, workday_on_holiday = 0.02231496147956, 
month_3 = 0.0172067242969555, month_6 = 0.0151089321051142, text_fog = 0.0119331553129859, 
month_2 = 0.004686956213666, text_light_rain = 0.00222796628025926, 
text_passing_clouds = 0.00213700559004825, text_sunny = 0.00117576091734465, 
weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0, protocol_active = 0), c(wind = 0.317176884816342, 
temp = 0.186585429980718, month_10 = 0.114666912663031, month_11 = 0.104605599640779, 
barometer = 0.09860398214251, text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0981445614080669, 
month_7 = 0.086645777661902, weekday = 0.0827571745079603, month_3 = 0.0822469143395219, 
holiday = 0.0741225284600942, humidity = 0.0680909881825519, 
month_8 = 0.0676141235433077, month_1 = 0.0666523905343389, month_4 = 0.057138819125979, 
month_9 = 0.0566241708282194, workday_on_holiday = 0.0514050400134423, 
text_scattered_clouds = 0.0386366823825728, month_2 = 0.0275814191334069, 
month_6 = 0.0180563169006692, month_5 = 0.0171425190230017, text_fog = 0.0147302871581154, 
text_rain = 0.0113228506870373, month_12 = 0.00608702311249765, 
text_light_rain = 0.00384076425344412, text_passing_clouds = 0.00162419812395092, 
text_sunny = 0.00161398823166901, weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0, 
protocol_active = 0), c(wind = 0.375885075304381, temp = 0.196911627075252, 
month_1 = 0.138145776167852, month_10 = 0.1084922540901, month_7 = 0.102679471840915, 
text_mostly_cloudy = 0.101000594539934, humidity = 0.0873952553634127, 
holiday = 0.0831717698088636, weekday = 0.0709255464503129, month_11 = 0.0684159875069171, 
month_4 = 0.0625302634603284, month_8 = 0.0597528607537757, month_9 = 0.0577152460643418, 
barometer = 0.0573343434453839, workday_on_holiday = 0.0532975932012499, 
month_3 = 0.0431124968933724, month_12 = 0.0300806329768474, 
text_scattered_clouds = 0.0287391537020907, month_2 = 0.0263872490630998, 
text_rain = 0.023765753120286, month_5 = 0.0137840943180421, 
text_fog = 0.00944782494843987, month_6 = 0.00926343392612626, 
text_light_rain = 0.00513122997652807, text_passing_clouds = 0.00192773997607476, 
text_sunny = 0.000749526165263181, weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0, 
protocol_active = 0), c(wind = 0.380077804633114, temp = 0.193910785717298, 
month_8 = 0.134010390554593, month_11 = 0.13263544712777, month_1 = 0.108483703190367, 
humidity = 0.0857712876190871, holiday = 0.0789236757853526, 
barometer = 0.0758084804113203, month_10 = 0.0755415201722963, 
text_mostly_cloudy = 0.0680279704685786, workday_on_holiday = 0.0658503648376073, 
weekday = 0.0563462752284063, month_4 = 0.054099467118469, month_7 = 0.0467023095318018, 
month_3 = 0.0433152559594331, month_6 = 0.0356285987785469, text_scattered_clouds = 0.0320350306800973, 
month_9 = 0.0316930312848571, protocol_active = 0.0258647354336702, 
month_12 = 0.0173648500177142, month_5 = 0.013542126122798, text_fog = 0.0127799333001967, 
month_2 = 0.0054027507247214, text_light_rain = 0.00488149158866038, 
text_passing_clouds = 0.00411573011748326, text_rain = 0.0039578812850956, 
text_sunny = 0.00152551980949809, weekend = 0, weekend_on_holiday = 0
)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we can do a double `map` and avoid loading multiple packages

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(myList, ~ map_dfr(.x, as.list) )
# A tibble: 20 x 29
#   protocol_active  wind holiday month_10 month_8  temp month_11 humidity weekday month_1 text_scattered_… month_4 month_3 month_12 month_7
#             <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>            <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1         0.477   0.422  0.238    0.174   0.146  0.136   0.117    0.0981  0.0936  0.0758           0.0714  0.0459  0.0446  0.0401   0.0397
# 2         0.428   0.409  0.0866   0.0551  0.143  0.138   0.275    0.0898  0.131   0.0596           0.0490  0.0420  0.0405  0.0451   0.0327
# 3         0.00647 0.337  0.199    0.144   0.0588 0.144   0.137    0.0828  0.0824  0.192            0.101   0.0573  0.0265  0.0738   0.0263
# 4         0.457   0.387  0.166    0.0699  0.0830 0.149   0.272    0.0930  0.106   0.0928           0.0523  0.0415  0.0187  0.0184   0.0420
# 5         0.0535  0.286  0.155    0.150   0.0472 0.135   0.164    0.0645  0.0990  0.180            0.0775  0.0542  0.0207  0.0892   0.0337
# 6         0.0420  0.328  0.161    0.114   0.0438 0.122   0.130    0.0605  0.0832  0.175            0.123   0.0584  0.0339  0.0997   0.0318
# 7         0       0.318  0.185    0.133   0.0488 0.136   0.192    0.0683  0.0752  0.0980           0.0996  0.0230  0.0190  0.0411   0.0589
# 8         0.515   0.369  0.185    0.0513  0.112  0.149   0.235    0.0832  0.136   0.0524           0.0450  0.0623  0.0141  0.00527  0.0346
# 9         0.581   0.389  0.158    0.0610  0.0770 0.120   0.245    0.0738  0.123   0.0838           0.0591  0.0288  0.0259  0.00949  0.0255
#10         0.474   0.422  0.183    0.188   0.0873 0.136   0.105    0.0668  0.102   0.0742           0.0589  0.0641  0.0389  0.104    0.0352
#11         0       0.347  0.112    0.110   0.120  0.205   0.0950   0.114   0.0603  0.0679           0.0426  0.0677  0.0465  0.0240   0.0523
#12         0.547   0.444  0.206    0.139   0.0407 0.144   0.106    0.0702  0.120   0.0371           0.0229  0.0847  0.0250  0.0331   0.0236
#13         0.518   0.469  0.116    0.0392  0.128  0.198   0.0499   0.109   0.0970  0.105            0.0123  0.0304  0.0475  0.0521   0.0346
#14         0       0.363  0.0362   0.105   0.0479 0.157   0.0354   0.0763  0.0883  0.0369           0.0275  0.0541  0.0605  0.114    0.102 
#15         0.620   0.457  0.181    0.0885  0.0342 0.141   0.129    0.0470  0.114   0.0733           0.0253  0.0754  0.0566  0.0465   0.0201
#16         0.609   0.456  0.149    0.132   0.0228 0.140   0.117    0.0678  0.103   0.0712           0.0248  0.0701  0.0289  0.0408   0.0255
#17         0       0.341  0.0981   0.137   0.0646 0.182   0.0703   0.0585  0.0661  0.119            0.0295  0.0550  0.0172  0.0228   0.0790
#18         0       0.317  0.0741   0.115   0.0676 0.187   0.105    0.0681  0.0828  0.0667           0.0386  0.0571  0.0822  0.00609  0.0866
#19         0       0.376  0.0832   0.108   0.0598 0.197   0.0684   0.0874  0.0709  0.138            0.0287  0.0625  0.0431  0.0301   0.103 
#20         0.0259  0.380  0.0789   0.0755  0.134  0.194   0.133    0.0858  0.0563  0.108            0.0320  0.0541  0.0433  0.0174   0.0467
# … with 14 more variables: month_9 <dbl>, month_6 <dbl>, barometer <dbl>, month_5 <dbl>, text_light_rain <dbl>, month_2 <dbl>,
#   text_mostly_cloudy <dbl>, text_sunny <dbl>, text_fog <dbl>, workday_on_holiday <dbl>, text_passing_clouds <dbl>, text_rain <dbl>,
#   weekend <dbl>, weekend_on_holiday <dbl>
```

---

Or another option is `unnest_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
map_dfr(myList, ~ tibble(col = .x) %>%
                       unnest_wider(col))
# A tibble: 20 x 29
#   protocol_active  wind holiday month_10 month_8  temp month_11 humidity weekday month_1 text_scattered_… month_4 month_3 month_12 month_7
#             <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>            <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1         0.477   0.422  0.238    0.174   0.146  0.136   0.117    0.0981  0.0936  0.0758           0.0714  0.0459  0.0446  0.0401   0.0397
# 2         0.428   0.409  0.0866   0.0551  0.143  0.138   0.275    0.0898  0.131   0.0596           0.0490  0.0420  0.0405  0.0451   0.0327
# 3         0.00647 0.337  0.199    0.144   0.0588 0.144   0.137    0.0828  0.0824  0.192            0.101   0.0573  0.0265  0.0738   0.0263
# 4         0.457   0.387  0.166    0.0699  0.0830 0.149   0.272    0.0930  0.106   0.0928           0.0523  0.0415  0.0187  0.0184   0.0420
# 5         0.0535  0.286  0.155    0.150   0.0472 0.135   0.164    0.0645  0.0990  0.180            0.0775  0.0542  0.0207  0.0892   0.0337
# 6         0.0420  0.328  0.161    0.114   0.0438 0.122   0.130    0.0605  0.0832  0.175            0.123   0.0584  0.0339  0.0997   0.0318
# 7         0       0.318  0.185    0.133   0.0488 0.136   0.192    0.0683  0.0752  0.0980           0.0996  0.0230  0.0190  0.0411   0.0589
# 8         0.515   0.369  0.185    0.0513  0.112  0.149   0.235    0.0832  0.136   0.0524           0.0450  0.0623  0.0141  0.00527  0.0346
# 9         0.581   0.389  0.158    0.0610  0.0770 0.120   0.245    0.0738  0.123   0.0838           0.0591  0.0288  0.0259  0.00949  0.0255
#10         0.474   0.422  0.183    0.188   0.0873 0.136   0.105    0.0668  0.102   0.0742           0.0589  0.0641  0.0389  0.104    0.0352
#11         0       0.347  0.112    0.110   0.120  0.205   0.0950   0.114   0.0603  0.0679           0.0426  0.0677  0.0465  0.0240   0.0523
#12         0.547   0.444  0.206    0.139   0.0407 0.144   0.106    0.0702  0.120   0.0371           0.0229  0.0847  0.0250  0.0331   0.0236
#13         0.518   0.469  0.116    0.0392  0.128  0.198   0.0499   0.109   0.0970  0.105            0.0123  0.0304  0.0475  0.0521   0.0346
#14         0       0.363  0.0362   0.105   0.0479 0.157   0.0354   0.0763  0.0883  0.0369           0.0275  0.0541  0.0605  0.114    0.102 
#15         0.620   0.457  0.181    0.0885  0.0342 0.141   0.129    0.0470  0.114   0.0733           0.0253  0.0754  0.0566  0.0465   0.0201
#16         0.609   0.456  0.149    0.132   0.0228 0.140   0.117    0.0678  0.103   0.0712           0.0248  0.0701  0.0289  0.0408   0.0255
#17         0       0.341  0.0981   0.137   0.0646 0.182   0.0703   0.0585  0.0661  0.119            0.0295  0.0550  0.0172  0.0228   0.0790
#18         0       0.317  0.0741   0.115   0.0676 0.187   0.105    0.0681  0.0828  0.0667           0.0386  0.0571  0.0822  0.00609  0.0866
#19         0       0.376  0.0832   0.108   0.0598 0.197   0.0684   0.0874  0.0709  0.138            0.0287  0.0625  0.0431  0.0301   0.103 
#20         0.0259  0.380  0.0789   0.0755  0.134  0.194   0.133    0.0858  0.0563  0.108            0.0320  0.0541  0.0433  0.0174   0.0467
# … with 14 more variables: month_9 <dbl>, month_6 <dbl>, barometer <dbl>, month_5 <dbl>, text_light_rain <dbl>, month_2 <dbl>,
#   text_mostly_cloudy <dbl>, text_sunny <dbl>, text_fog <dbl>, workday_on_holiday <dbl>, text_passing_clouds <dbl>, text_rain <dbl>,
#   weekend <dbl>, weekend_on_holiday <dbl>
```

---

Or another option is `reduce/bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(myList, reduce, bind_rows)
# A tibble: 20 x 29
#   protocol_active  wind holiday month_10 month_8  temp month_11 humidity weekday month_1 text_scattered_… month_4 month_3 month_12 month_7
#             <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>            <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1         0.477   0.422  0.238    0.174   0.146  0.136   0.117    0.0981  0.0936  0.0758           0.0714  0.0459  0.0446  0.0401   0.0397
# 2         0.428   0.409  0.0866   0.0551  0.143  0.138   0.275    0.0898  0.131   0.0596           0.0490  0.0420  0.0405  0.0451   0.0327
# 3         0.00647 0.337  0.199    0.144   0.0588 0.144   0.137    0.0828  0.0824  0.192            0.101   0.0573  0.0265  0.0738   0.0263
# 4         0.457   0.387  0.166    0.0699  0.0830 0.149   0.272    0.0930  0.106   0.0928           0.0523  0.0415  0.0187  0.0184   0.0420
# 5         0.0535  0.286  0.155    0.150   0.0472 0.135   0.164    0.0645  0.0990  0.180            0.0775  0.0542  0.0207  0.0892   0.0337
# 6         0.0420  0.328  0.161    0.114   0.0438 0.122   0.130    0.0605  0.0832  0.175            0.123   0.0584  0.0339  0.0997   0.0318
# 7         0       0.318  0.185    0.133   0.0488 0.136   0.192    0.0683  0.0752  0.0980           0.0996  0.0230  0.0190  0.0411   0.0589
# 8         0.515   0.369  0.185    0.0513  0.112  0.149   0.235    0.0832  0.136   0.0524           0.0450  0.0623  0.0141  0.00527  0.0346
# 9         0.581   0.389  0.158    0.0610  0.0770 0.120   0.245    0.0738  0.123   0.0838           0.0591  0.0288  0.0259  0.00949  0.0255
#10         0.474   0.422  0.183    0.188   0.0873 0.136   0.105    0.0668  0.102   0.0742           0.0589  0.0641  0.0389  0.104    0.0352
#11         0       0.347  0.112    0.110   0.120  0.205   0.0950   0.114   0.0603  0.0679           0.0426  0.0677  0.0465  0.0240   0.0523
#12         0.547   0.444  0.206    0.139   0.0407 0.144   0.106    0.0702  0.120   0.0371           0.0229  0.0847  0.0250  0.0331   0.0236
#13         0.518   0.469  0.116    0.0392  0.128  0.198   0.0499   0.109   0.0970  0.105            0.0123  0.0304  0.0475  0.0521   0.0346
#14         0       0.363  0.0362   0.105   0.0479 0.157   0.0354   0.0763  0.0883  0.0369           0.0275  0.0541  0.0605  0.114    0.102 
#15         0.620   0.457  0.181    0.0885  0.0342 0.141   0.129    0.0470  0.114   0.0733           0.0253  0.0754  0.0566  0.0465   0.0201
#16         0.609   0.456  0.149    0.132   0.0228 0.140   0.117    0.0678  0.103   0.0712           0.0248  0.0701  0.0289  0.0408   0.0255
#17         0       0.341  0.0981   0.137   0.0646 0.182   0.0703   0.0585  0.0661  0.119            0.0295  0.0550  0.0172  0.0228   0.0790
#18         0       0.317  0.0741   0.115   0.0676 0.187   0.105    0.0681  0.0828  0.0667           0.0386  0.0571  0.0822  0.00609  0.0866
#19         0       0.376  0.0832   0.108   0.0598 0.197   0.0684   0.0874  0.0709  0.138            0.0287  0.0625  0.0431  0.0301   0.103 
#20         0.0259  0.380  0.0789   0.0755  0.134  0.194   0.133    0.0858  0.0563  0.108            0.0320  0.0541  0.0433  0.0174   0.0467
# … with 14 more variables: month_9 <dbl>, month_6 <dbl>, barometer <dbl>, month_5 <dbl>, text_light_rain <dbl>, month_2 <dbl>,
#   text_mostly_cloudy <dbl>, text_sunny <dbl>, text_fog <dbl>, workday_on_holiday <dbl>, text_passing_clouds <dbl>, text_rain <dbl>,
#   weekend <dbl>, weekend_on_holiday <dbl>
>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your list contains lists of named vectors.  You can use `bind_rows()` if you splice the nested lists.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map_df(myList, ~bind_rows(!!!.x))

# A tibble: 20 x 29
   protocol_active  wind holiday month_10 month_8  temp month_11 humidity weekday month_1
             <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1         0.477   0.422  0.238    0.174   0.146  0.136   0.117    0.0981  0.0936  0.0758
 2         0.428   0.409  0.0866   0.0551  0.143  0.138   0.275    0.0898  0.131   0.0596
 3         0.00647 0.337  0.199    0.144   0.0588 0.144   0.137    0.0828  0.0824  0.192 
 4         0.457   0.387  0.166    0.0699  0.0830 0.149   0.272    0.0930  0.106   0.0928
 5         0.0535  0.286  0.155    0.150   0.0472 0.135   0.164    0.0645  0.0990  0.180 
 6         0.0420  0.328  0.161    0.114   0.0438 0.122   0.130    0.0605  0.0832  0.175 
 7         0       0.318  0.185    0.133   0.0488 0.136   0.192    0.0683  0.0752  0.0980
 8         0.515   0.369  0.185    0.0513  0.112  0.149   0.235    0.0832  0.136   0.0524
 9         0.581   0.389  0.158    0.0610  0.0770 0.120   0.245    0.0738  0.123   0.0838
10         0.474   0.422  0.183    0.188   0.0873 0.136   0.105    0.0668  0.102   0.0742
11         0       0.347  0.112    0.110   0.120  0.205   0.0950   0.114   0.0603  0.0679
12         0.547   0.444  0.206    0.139   0.0407 0.144   0.106    0.0702  0.120   0.0371
13         0.518   0.469  0.116    0.0392  0.128  0.198   0.0499   0.109   0.0970  0.105 
14         0       0.363  0.0362   0.105   0.0479 0.157   0.0354   0.0763  0.0883  0.0369
15         0.620   0.457  0.181    0.0885  0.0342 0.141   0.129    0.0470  0.114   0.0733
16         0.609   0.456  0.149    0.132   0.0228 0.140   0.117    0.0678  0.103   0.0712
17         0       0.341  0.0981   0.137   0.0646 0.182   0.0703   0.0585  0.0661  0.119 
18         0       0.317  0.0741   0.115   0.0676 0.187   0.105    0.0681  0.0828  0.0667
19         0       0.376  0.0832   0.108   0.0598 0.197   0.0684   0.0874  0.0709  0.138 
20         0.0259  0.380  0.0789   0.0755  0.134  0.194   0.133    0.0858  0.0563  0.108 
# ... with 19 more variables: text_scattered_clouds <dbl>, month_4 <dbl>, month_3 <dbl>,
#   month_12 <dbl>, month_7 <dbl>, month_9 <dbl>, month_6 <dbl>, barometer <dbl>, month_5 <dbl>,
#   text_light_rain <dbl>, month_2 <dbl>, text_mostly_cloudy <dbl>, text_sunny <dbl>,
#   text_fog <dbl>, workday_on_holiday <dbl>, text_passing_clouds <dbl>, text_rain <dbl>,
#   weekend <dbl>, weekend_on_holiday <dbl>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to create a data frame from a double nested list of named numeric vectors.

Here is an alternative way which flattens the first list level, turns the named vectors into lists which then are combined into a data frame (actually a data.table) by matching column names:

```
library(magrittr) # piping used here to improve readability
myList %>% 
  unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>% 
  lapply(as.list) %>% 
  data.table::rbindlist(use.names = TRUE)
```

As a proof, here is the output of `str()`

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    20 obs. of  29 variables:
>  $ protocol_active      : num  0.47669 0.42776 0.00647 0.45722 0.0535 ...
>  $ wind                 : num  0.422 0.409 0.337 0.387 0.286 ...
>  $ holiday              : num  0.2379 0.0866 0.1988 0.1661 0.1545 ...
>  $ month_10             : num  0.1741 0.0551 0.1444 0.0699 0.1501 ...
>  $ month_8              : num  0.1462 0.143 0.0588 0.083 0.0472 ...
>  $ temp                 : num  0.136 0.138 0.144 0.149 0.135 ...
>  $ month_11             : num  0.117 0.275 0.137 0.272 0.164 ...
>  $ humidity             : num  0.0981 0.0898 0.0828 0.093 0.0645 ...
>  $ weekday              : num  0.0936 0.1311 0.0824 0.106 0.099 ...
>  $ month_1              : num  0.0758 0.0596 0.1924 0.0928 0.1798 ...
>  $ text_scattered_clouds: num  0.0714 0.049 0.1012 0.0523 0.0775 ...
>  $ month_4              : num  0.0459 0.042 0.0573 0.0415 0.0542 ...
>  $ month_3              : num  0.0446 0.0405 0.0265 0.0187 0.0207 ...
>  $ month_12             : num  0.0401 0.0451 0.0738 0.0184 0.0892 ...
>  $ month_7              : num  0.0397 0.0327 0.0263 0.042 0.0337 ...
>  $ month_9              : num  0.0314 0.0293 0.0259 0.0375 0.0313 ...
>  $ month_6              : num  0.0307 0.0338 0.0403 0.0217 0.0473 ...
>  $ barometer            : num  0.0298 0.0356 0.0396 0.0431 0.0359 ...
>  $ month_5              : num  0.0276 0.0359 0.0595 0.0355 0.0524 ...
>  $ text_light_rain      : num  0.01658 0.00943 0.00632 0.0201 0.00611 ...
>  $ month_2              : num  0.0166 0.018 0.013 0.0272 0.0163 ...
>  $ text_mostly_cloudy   : num  0.0121 0.0271 0.048 0.0298 0.0475 ...
>  $ text_sunny           : num  0.00941 0.0103 0.01311 0.00998 0.01055 ...
>  $ text_fog             : num  0.00925 0.00807 0.00586 0.05253 0.00589 ...
>  $ workday_on_holiday   : num  0.00284 0.00241 0.00982 0.01957 0.02553 ...
>  $ text_passing_clouds  : num  0.0015 0.01187 0.00684 0.02744 0.00752 ...
>  $ text_rain            : num  0.001312 0.000057 0.000405 0.003292 0.001999 ...
>  $ weekend              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>  $ weekend_on_holiday   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, one option could be :

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(myList,function(x) 
               do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(y) data.frame(t(y))))))


#   protocol_active  wind holiday month_10 month_8  temp month_11 humidity ...
#1          0.47669 0.422  0.2379   0.1741  0.1462 0.136   0.1171   0.0981 ...
#2          0.42776 0.409  0.0866   0.0551  0.1430 0.138   0.2751   0.0898 ...
#3          0.00647 0.337  0.1988   0.1444  0.0588 0.144   0.1373   0.0828 ...
#4          0.45722 0.387  0.1661   0.0699  0.0830 0.149   0.2715   0.0930 ...
#5          0.05350 0.286  0.1545   0.1501  0.0472 0.135   0.1643   0.0645 ...
#6          0.04196 0.328  0.1608   0.1137  0.0438 0.122   0.1295   0.0605 ...
#7          0.00000 0.318  0.1854   0.1328  0.0488 0.136   0.1919   0.0683 ...
#8          0.51500 0.369  0.1846   0.0513  0.1115 0.149   0.2346   0.0832 ...
#9          0.58129 0.389  0.1580   0.0610  0.0770 0.120   0.2446   0.0738 ...
#10         0.47424 0.422  0.1826   0.1878  0.0873 0.136   0.1046   0.0668 ...
#11         0.00000 0.347  0.1122   0.1097  0.1196 0.205   0.0950   0.1144 ...
#12         0.54655 0.444  0.2058   0.1391  0.0407 0.144   0.1057   0.0702 ...
#13         0.51817 0.469  0.1157   0.0392  0.1279 0.198   0.0499   0.1090 ...
#14         0.00000 0.363  0.0362   0.1050  0.0479 0.157   0.0354   0.0763 ...
#15         0.61956 0.457  0.1811   0.0885  0.0342 0.141   0.1291   0.0470 ...
#16         0.60933 0.456  0.1486   0.1324  0.0228 0.140   0.1172   0.0678 ...
#17         0.00000 0.341  0.0981   0.1370  0.0646 0.182   0.0703   0.0585 ...
#18         0.00000 0.317  0.0741   0.1147  0.0676 0.187   0.1046   0.0681 ...
#19         0.00000 0.376  0.0832   0.1085  0.0598 0.197   0.0684   0.0874 ...
#20         0.02586 0.380  0.0789   0.0755  0.1340 0.194   0.1326   0.0858 ...
```